# rpc pointer not showing the right result

Tags: c, rpc, xdr

So I'm trying to use some RPC function.

Basically I want to multiply 2 2*2 matrices, the client send 2 matrices the client calculates and sends the matrix.

The matrix received in my client isn't the one I sent.

```
// server.c
matrice* multiply(matrice2 *m2)
{ 
    matrice* res=&(matrice){.w=0.0,.x=0.0,.y=0.0,.z=0.0};
    res->w=m2->m.w*m2->n.w+m2->m.x*m2->n.y; // ww'+xy'
    res->x=m2->m.w*m2->n.x+m2->m.x*m2->n.z; // wx'+xz'
    res->y=m2->m.y*m2->n.w+m2->m.z*m2->n.y; // yw'+zy'
    res->z=m2->m.y*m2->n.x+m2->m.z+m2->n.z; // yx'+z'z

    return res;
}

int main(void)
{
    ...
    stat = registerrpc(PROGNUM, VERSNUM,PROCNUM, multiply, (xdrproc_t)xdr_matrice2, (xdrproc_t)xdr_matrice);
    svc_run();
}

//client.c
int main (int argc, char **argv)
{
    matrice m={1.0,2.0,3.0,4.0};
    matrice n={9.0,8.0,7.0,6.0};
    matrice2 donnees = {m , n};
    stat = callrpc(host, PROGNUM, VERSNUM, PROCNUM, (xdrproc_t) xdr_matrice2, (char *)&donnees, (xdrproc_t)xdr_matrice, (char *)&res);
}

//include.h
typedef struct { double w; double x; double y; double z; } matrice;
typedef struct { matrice m; matrice n; } matrice2;
bool_t xdr_matrice(XDR *, matrice *);
bool_t xdr_matrice2(XDR *, matrice2 *);

//xdr_matrice.c
bool_t xdr_matrice(XDR *xdrs, matrice *m)
{
    return xdr_double(xdrs,&(m->w)) && xdr_double(xdrs,&(m->x)) && xdr_double(xdrs,&(m->y)) && xdr_double(xdrs,&(m->z));
}

bool_t xdr_matrice2(XDR *xdrs, matrice2 *m2)
{
    return xdr_matrice(xdrs,&(m2->m)) && xdr_matrice(xdrs,&(m2->n));
}
```

Can someone explain me why it isn't working properly or which error I made ?

Comment: Your server's multiply seems to be returning a pointer to a local variable that will go out of scope when the function returns.

Comment: Perhaps if you declared `res` to be static and returned its address, then it would work.  I'm assuming that xdr ensures that your server's function (and decoding and encoding) can't be executed in parallel.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was really stupid,
I just changed my multiply function to have a static `res` (and obviously `return &res` and changed `->` to `.`) and it worked ...